# Custom Admin Edit form not displayed

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, adminform, edit

I have created a custom module using \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container form with Magento2.3 and I am facing issue while edit form is not showing in Magento Cloud, But local environment is working fine.

I am testing, the Block action is loaded, But the Edit/Form.php not loading.

[image]

Below is my code.

**The Controller [import.php]**

```
 <?php
namespace Test\api\Controller\Adminhtml\AdList;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class import extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
  /**
   * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
   */
  private $coreRegistry;
  /**
   * @var \Test\api\Model\AdsTableFactory
   */
  private $adsTableFactory;

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
   * @param \Test\api\Model\AdsTableFactory $adsTableFactory
   */
  public function __construct(
      \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
      \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
      \Test\api\Model\AdsTableFactory $adsTableFactory
  ) {
      parent::__construct($context);
      $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
      $this->adsTableFactory = $adsTableFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Mapped Grid List page.
   * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
   */
  public function execute()
  {
      $rowId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
      $rowData = $this->adsTableFactory->create();
      /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
      if ($rowId) {
          $rowData = $rowData->load($rowId);
          $rowName = $rowData->getName();
          if (!$rowData->getId()) {
              $this->messageManager->addError(__('row data no longer exist.'));
              $this->_redirect('test_app/AdList/rowdata');
              return;
          }
      }
      $this->coreRegistry->register('row_data', $rowData);
      $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
      $title = $rowId ? __('Edit Row').$rowName : __('Add Row');
      $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($title);
      return $resultPage;
  }

  protected function _isAllowed()
  {
       return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Test_Api::test_app');
  }
}
?>
```

**Layout XML [test_app_adlist_import.xml]**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
          <block class="Test\Api\Block\Adminhtml\AdList\CustomBlock" cacheable="false" name="test_app_adlist_import" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**The Block Action [CustomBlock.php]**

```
<?php
namespace Test\api\Block\Adminhtml\AdList;

class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container
{

  protected $_coreRegistry = null;

   /**
    * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    * @param array $data
    */
   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       array $data = []
   ) {
       $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   /**
    * Initialize form
    * Add standard buttons
    * Add "Save and Continue" button
    *
    * @return void
    */
   protected function _construct()
   {
         $this->_objectId = 'id';
         $this->_blockGroup = 'Test_Api';
         $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_adlist';
         parent::_construct();

         if ($this->_isAllowedAction('Test_Api::test_app')) {
             $this->buttonList->update('save', 'label', __('Save'));
         } else {
             $this->buttonList->remove('save');
         }
         $this->buttonList->remove('reset');
   }

   /**
    * Getter for form header text
    *
    * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
    */
   public function getHeaderText()
   {
     return __('Add RoW Data');
   }


    /**
     * Check permission for passed action. *
     * @param string $resourceId
     *
     * @return bool
      */
     protected function _isAllowedAction($resourceId)
     {
       return $this->_authorization->isAllowed($resourceId);
     }


    /**
     * Get form action URL.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormActionUrl()
    {
        if ($this->hasFormActionUrl()) {
            return $this->getData('form_action_url');
        }

        return $this->getUrl('*/*/save');
    }

}
?>
```

**The Edit Form [Form.php]**

```
<?php
namespace Test\api\Block\Adminhtml\AdList\Edit;
/**
 * Adminhtml Add New Row Form.
 */
class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Prepare form.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {


        $dateFormat = $this->_localeDate->getDateFormat(\IntlDateFormatter::SHORT);
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('row_data');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => [
                            'id' => 'edit_form',
                            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                            'action' => $this->getData('action'),
                            'method' => 'post'
                        ]
            ]
        );
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('test_');
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
'base_fieldset',
['legend' => __('Add Row'), 'class' => 'fieldset-wide']
);
        $fieldset->addField(
            'name',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'name',
                'label' => __('Name'),
                'id' => 'name',
                'title' => __('name'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
            ]
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento module name should start with Capital letter. In your case, this is **api**. Change this to **Api**. Also your namespace should change. Ex.

> namespace Test\Api\Block\Adminhtml\AdList\Edit;

Change this for all class.

Comment: it seems not to work; I updated the namespace and test, but the Edit/Form.php still not loading yet

Comment: the name of the block action, can I use AdList ? or Adlist ?

Comment: Yes, you can use AdList.

Comment: You can add module somewhere for cheking

Comment: What does the module moving to somewhere mean?
After changed, the namespace from 'api' to 'Api'. 
I also have tried the controller, layout, and block. Every component has been connected. 
But, only one thing does understand, while the program goes into the block action. Both __construct and _construct are executed, but finally doesn't execute _prepareLayout function.

Comment: I found something related this, let me share it. In the block action, I had set `$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_adlist';`. According _vendor/magento/framework/Code/NameBuilder.php_ there will run the program `$className = str_replace(' ', $separator, ucwords(str_replace($separator, ' ', $string)));` finally the class name will be  `$className = 'Test\\Api\\Block\\Adminhtml\\Adlist\\Edit\\Form';`. But since the block called **AdList**, so I should set the controller be ``$this->_controller = 'adminhtml_adList';`

Comment: Finally, the form show up. Anyway, thank you for your reply and inspiration

Comment: Great, Should avoid deprecating grid creation. Use ui component.